What movie (or TV episode) has James Earl Jones discussing "being a daddy"?
The popular parody video Vader Sessions dubs lines from other productions James Earl Jones was involved in over scenes of Darth Vader, to hilarious effect.
I've been curious about the source of one of the lines, but haven't found it. At about 2:50 he says:

Listen, can I explain something to you about being a daddy? The daddy is the breadwinner, you dig what I'm saying? You don't win that bread, you just don't come around.

I've done lots of Googling of James Earl Jones films and portions of the quote, but have come up empty. I'd rather not watch all his films one by one just to find out. Does anybody know where it comes from?

It may not even be from a film.  He narrates a some books, too (including the entire New Testament).

If I had to guess, I'd say one of the "blacksploitation" movies of the 70's.

It's from the movie Claudine 1974. Jones plays a garbage man named Rupert dating a single mom (played by Diahann Carroll). He's reticent about dating her because she's got six children and you find out in the movie that he's got his own children and his wages get garnished, which causes him to run off for a short period. The dialogue is him talking to Claudine's children.

Are you able to provide the quote in context? That would make this good answer even better.

@Thunderforge Found the full movie. The quote occurs at about 1:27:00.

@MrBultitude Would you be able to transcribe the quote in context? I'd do it myself, but I'm on mobile right now.
